# 413 Payload Too Large issue with Springboot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using Springboot. 
I have implemented `new ResponseEntity(errors, HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)` to return 413 as the status code and **Payload Too Large** as the status message. But I am getting 413 **Request Entity Too Large**.

The `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` enum has both `PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE(413, "Payload Too Large")` and `REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE(413, "Request Entity Too Large")` constants. Due to this somewhere always it is picking **Request Entity Too Large**. To avoid this issue I created a filter and set the status message explicitly on `HttpServletResponse`. But, that also is giving status message as **Request Entity Too Large**.

If anyone came across the above issue? Have any clues?

Comment: Did you check that you are getting actual status message? Did you check with `curl -vv`? I wouldn't rely on status messages at all. I wouldn't hope that the servlet server would preserve one, neither the proxy server, and even the client.